# Null pointer reference from Adapter setOnClickListener

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I have the following code and I'm getting a null pointer exception (see below). I want to retrieve the userName pointed to by the view holder. I've tried even to retrieve it via view (v) itself but I got the same exception. I don't understand why the value is null.

```
    public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;


        public ContactAdapter(Context context) {

            mContext = context;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_contact, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        ViewHolder vv = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
                        TextView tv = (TextView) vv.userName.getText(); // Exception here - Line 120
                    }catch(Exception xx){

                    }
                }
     });
}

    private class ViewHolder {

            TextView userName;
            ImageView add, delete, block,profImage;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {

                userName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
                add = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.add);
                delete = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.delete);
                block = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.block);
                profImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            }
        }
```

Here is the exception:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLm6i.gif)

Comment: I think you need to first setTag. holder.delete.setTag(holder);

Comment: In this _ViewHolder vv = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();_ u r getting tag for delete button _v.getTag()_ and u didn't set tag for delete button so getting NPE.

Answer (score 0):

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    ViewHolder vv = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
                    TextView tv = (TextView) vv.userName.getText(); 
                }catch(Exception xx){

                }
            }
 });
```

have you tried this inside the viewholder constructor... I think you are getting null pointer exception because you are setting on click listner on holder.delete

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'ViewHolder holder;' by 'final ViewHolder holder;' and in the onClick Method, just access the views by doing 'holder.userName.getText()' etc...

Comment: My pleasure! If your question is answered, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
ViewHolder vv = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    ViewHolder vv = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
                    TextView tv = (TextView) vv.userName.getText(); // Exception here - Line 120
                }catch(Exception xx){

                }
            }
 });
```

You set tag for your `convertView`, but you `getTag()` from convertView's child. so it'll be `null`

To fix it:

1. Change your ViewHolder to final

   final ViewHolder holder;
2. get text directly from your holder

   ```
   holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   try {
                       TextView tv = (TextView) holder.userName.getText();
                   }catch(Exception xx){

                   }
               }
    });
   ```